# Filling algorithm from edges to center in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas

I'm create a slicer for RepRap machine.

I got stuck at programming filling algorithm that would climb like this:

[image: animation] [image: animation]

It's kind of flood fill, but **it must go from edge to center like a spiral**. The path generated by algorithm is essential for the machine.

Do somebody know how to solve it? Thanks

**Answered by phenxd**

[image: animation]

Comment: I'd imagine what you'd have to do is look at `img[x - 1][y]` and `img[x][y - 1]`, and if either of them are not `1` then change the color of `img[x][y]`.

Comment: Do you know the x and y coordinates of your starting point?

Comment: findFirstPixel() {
  for(var x = 0; x < this.w; x++) {
   for(var y = 0; y < this.h; y++) {
    if(this.print[x][y]) return { x, y }
   }
  }
 }

Comment: Can´t imagine a simpler solution than using convex hull, might be wrong though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest for you is to try and implement your own variation of the [floodfilling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

Though, since you want to paint from the outer bound, instead of checking the up, down, left and right neighbors in the same order everytime, you should do it relatively from the 'direction' you are currently drawing.

Ex.

> First pixel is on the left.

```
check left : skip
check down : draw   

MOVING DOWN   
    check left : skip   
    check down : skip   
    check right : draw   

MOVING RIGHT    
    check down : draw   // We rotated the order by 90 degrees!

etc.
```

The goal is to always check the pixel on the right of the current direction so that we will always be on the outer bound of our drawing